# GHCI swears on "=" symbol

Tags: haskell

The purpose was to sort the list of tuples (names) by tuple's 2nd element.

```
module Learn where
import Data.List

names = [("Ian", "Curtis"),("Bernard","Sumner"),("Peter","Hook"),("Stephen","Morris")]

compareLastNames name1 name2 = if lastName1>lastName2
 then GT else if lastName1<lastName2 then LT else EQ where lastName1=snd name1 lastName2=snd name2
```

then I would call

```
sortBy compareLastNames names
```

GHCI doesnt want to swallow that file and is swearing on "=". Cannot find out why
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sh3I.jpg)

Comment: The main issue is that the part `lastName1=snd name1 lastName2` is parsed as if you passed two arguments to `snd`. Then the next `=` is a parse error. TO make two different definitions, put them on distinct lines, or separate them using `;`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use proper whitespace in defining the function:

```
compareLastNames name1 name2 = if lastName1>lastName2then GT else if lastName1<lastName2 then LT else EQ 
    where 
      lastName1=snd name1 
      lastName2=snd name2
```

This is much simpler to define using pattern matching, though, since explicit calls to `snd` are avoided.

```
compareLastNames (_, lastName1) (_, lastName2) = if lastName1 > lastName2 then GT else if lastName1<lastName2 then LT else EQ
```

You can also use the `compare` function from the Prelude:

```
compareLastNames (_, lastName1) (_, lastName2) = compare lastName1 lastName2
```

or `Data.Ord.comparing`

```
import Data.Ord
compareLastNames name1 name2 = comparing snd name1 name2
-- compareLastNames = comparing snd
```

Comment: Since you're giving more idiomatic examples, I would also mention ```compare `on` snd```

Comment: `comparing` is definitely more idiomatic than that suggestion.